# Убрать мерцание при ховере изменяеться высота карточки и нижний блок отключаеться и кнопка выпает из блока. при наведении снизу появляеться мерцании

Tags: css, html5, css-animation

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

body,p,h2{
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card{
position: relative;
padding-top: 20px;

width: 394px;
margin: auto;
border-radius: 15px;
border: 1px solid #FFF;
background: #FAFAFB;
transition: all 3s easu-in;



}
.card-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.row {
  margin: auto;
}

.card__image {
 
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #FFF;  
  background: #FAFAFB;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.card__title {
color: #282828;
font-family: Inter;
font-size: 20px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 600;
line-height: 26px; /* 130% */
text-align: left;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.card__desc {

color: #7E7E7E;
font-family: Inter;
font-size: 15px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 22px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.card__desc--span {
color: #282828;
font-family: Inter;
font-size: 15px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 700;
line-height: 22px; /* 146.667% */
}
.card__sum {
 
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.card__sum-amout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.card__sum-amout--numbers {
  color: #282828;
font-family: Inter;
font-size: 18px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 22px; /* 122.222% */
}
.card__sum-amout--desc {
  color: #7E7E7E;
font-family: Inter;
font-size: 15px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: normal;
}
.card__sum-ful-amout {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
.card__sum-ful-amout--numbers {
  color: #282828;
text-align: right;
font-family: Inter;
font-size: 18px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 700;
line-height: 22px; /* 122.222% */
}
.card__sum-ful-amout--desc {
  color: #7E7E7E;
font-family: Inter;
font-size: 15px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: normal;
}
.rectangel {

  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px; 
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #F5F5F5;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px 0px #E4E9EB inset;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.progress{
  display: flex;
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: linear-gradient(96deg, #82AFFF -46.61%, #2A75E6 101.71%);
}
.card__link {
  color: #282828;
text-align: center;
font-family: Inter;
font-size: 16px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 22px; /* 137.5% */
margin-bottom: 25px;
}
.card__btn {
position: relative;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #6e34e2b3;
background-image: conic-gradient(from 1turn,rgba(136,83,252,1),rgba(110,52,226,1));
padding: 19px 30px;
border-radius: 30px;
outline: none;
border: none;
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
font-family: Inter;
font-size: 18px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 500;
line-height: normal;
margin: 25px auto;
margin-top: 0;
}
.card__footer {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
  background: #E9EDF2;
 }
.card__footer-procent {
grid-column: 1 span;
display: flex;
margin-left: auto;
color: #282828;
text-align: right;
font-family: Inter;
font-size: 28px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 700;
line-height: 22px; /* 78.571% */
}
.card__footer-desc {
grid-column: 2 span;
display: flex;
color: #282828;
font-family: Inter;
font-size: 12px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: normal;
}

.card__footer-container {
  display: grid;
  gap:15px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.card:hover{
border-radius: 15px;
border: 1px solid #EB2764;
background: #FAFAFB;
transition: all 1s;

.card__btn {
position: absolute;
left: 30% ;
bottom: -30px;
margin: 0;
background-image: conic-gradient(from 1turn,rgba(136,83,252,.7),rgba(110,52,226,.7));
}
.card__footer {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity: 1s easy;
}
.card__link{
 margin: 0;
}
.card__footer-container{
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="row">
        <article class="card">
          <div class="card-container container">
            <img class="card__image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516627145497-ae6968895b74?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1440&q=80" alt="kids">
          <h2 class="card__title">Мельник Олеся</h2>
          <p class="card__desc"><span class="card__desc--span">Диагноз:</span>Врожденный порок сердца, синдром левосторонней гипоплазии сердца. Гибридное вмешательство – </p>
         <div class="card__sum">
           <div class="card__sum-amout">
             <span class="card__sum-amout--numbers">6500000 ₽</span>
             <span class="card__sum-amout--desc">уже собрано</span>
           </div>
           <div class="card__sum-ful-amout">
             <span class="card__sum-ful-amout--numbers">7000000 ₽</span>
             <span class="card__sum-ful-amout--desc">необходимо</span>
           </div> 
         </div> 
         <div class="rectangel">
           <span class="progress"></span>
         </div>
         <a href="" class="card__link">История Кати</a>
         <button class="card__btn" type="button">Хочу помочь</button>
          </div>
         <div class="card__footer">
          <div class="card__footer-container container">
             <p class="card__footer-procent">95%</p>
             <p class="card__footer-desc">уже собарно <br> до окончания сбора лишь 5% </p>
          </div>
         </div>
        </article>     
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Кроме появления красного бордера вокруг карточки по наведению больше ничего не происходит: ни изменения высоты, ни выпадения кнопки, ни мерцания. Возможно, код неполный?

Comment: блок пропадет один там 95 процентов . попробуй навести мышкой

Comment: Не-а, ничего не пропадает. да и не с чего пропадать - в коде только один ховер: `.card:hover{
border-radius: 15px;
border: 1px solid #EB2764;
background: #FAFAFB;
transition: all 1s;` Что-то не дописано, похоже

Comment: Ты что не видишь ниже весь css ? При ховере я обращаюсь к другим блокам еще

Comment: в сниппете только css работает - css не поддерживает вложенные блоки. поэтому эта часть просто не работает. Если ты используешь scss или другой процессор css - вставлять нужно конечный код

Comment: работает вложеность в цсс

Answer (score 0):

У тебя было несколько синтаксических ошибок в CSS коде, подправил в редакторе кода, вот посмотри результат:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

body,
p,
h2 {
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 20px;

    width: 394px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    background: #FAFAFB;
    transition: all 3s easu-in;



}

.card-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
    margin: auto;
}

.card__image {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    background: #FAFAFB;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.card__title {
    color: #282828;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 26px;
    /* 130% */
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.card__desc {

    color: #7E7E7E;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.card__desc--span {
    color: #282828;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 22px;
    /* 146.667% */
}

.card__sum {

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.card__sum-amout {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.card__sum-amout--numbers {
    color: #282828;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 22px;
    /* 122.222% */
}

.card__sum-amout--desc {
    color: #7E7E7E;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: normal;
}

.card__sum-ful-amout {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.card__sum-ful-amout--numbers {
    color: #282828;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 22px;
    /* 122.222% */
}

.card__sum-ful-amout--desc {
    color: #7E7E7E;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: normal;
}

.rectangel {

    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 4px 0px #E4E9EB inset;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.progress {
    display: flex;
    width: 95%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: linear-gradient(96deg, #82AFFF -46.61%, #2A75E6 101.71%);
}

.card__link {
    color: #282828;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 22px;
    /* 137.5% */
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.card__btn {
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #6e34e2b3;
    background-image: conic-gradient(from 1turn, rgba(136, 83, 252, 1), rgba(110, 52, 226, 1));
    padding: 19px 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 25px auto;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.card__footer {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
    background: #E9EDF2;
}

.card__footer-procent {
    grid-column: 1 span;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: auto;
    color: #282828;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 22px;
    /* 78.571% */
}

.card__footer-desc {
    grid-column: 2 span;
    display: flex;
    color: #282828;
    font-family: Inter;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: normal;
}

.card__footer-container {
    display: grid;
    gap: 15px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.card:hover {
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #EB2764;
    background: #FAFAFB;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.card__btn {
    position: absolute;
    left: 30%;
    bottom: -30px;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: conic-gradient(from 1turn, rgba(136, 83, 252, .7), rgba(110, 52, 226, .7));
}

.card__footer {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s easy;
}

.card__link {
    margin: 0;
}

.card__footer-container {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <article class="card">
                <div class="card-container container">
                    <img class="card__image"
                        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516627145497-ae6968895b74?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1440&q=80"
                        alt="kids">
                    <h2 class="card__title">Мельник Олеся</h2>
                    <p class="card__desc"><span class="card__desc--span">Диагноз:</span>Врожденный порок сердца, синдром
                        левосторонней гипоплазии сердца. Гибридное вмешательство – </p>
                    <div class="card__sum">
                        <div class="card__sum-amout">
                            <span class="card__sum-amout--numbers">6500000 ₽</span>
                            <span class="card__sum-amout--desc">уже собрано</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card__sum-ful-amout">
                            <span class="card__sum-ful-amout--numbers">7000000 ₽</span>
                            <span class="card__sum-ful-amout--desc">необходимо</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rectangel">
                        <span class="progress"></span>
                    </div>
                    <a href="" class="card__link">История Кати</a>
                    <button class="card__btn" type="button">Хочу помочь</button>
                </div>
                <div class="card__footer">
                    <div class="card__footer-container container">
                        <p class="card__footer-procent">95%</p>
                        <p class="card__footer-desc">уже собарно <br> до окончания сбора лишь 5% </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: ничем не помог, вложеность работает  и все нормально

Comment: Рад был помочь, но вероятно не до конца понимаю какой ожидаемый результат